# AWS SSM Start Session does not work in specific wifi network

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm, aws-session-manager

I'd like to preface by saying **this issue only occurs when connected to my home WiFi network as of Wednesday**. When I connect to my office network or to a mobile hotspot everything works as expected, in the past it worked on my home WiFi as well.

```
aws ssm start-session --target i-ABC --region us-west-2 --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=22'
```

After running the previous command on macOS I am unable to start an SSM session, it hangs and eventually times out. I've done the following steps to try and diagnose the issue:

1. Analyzing the Session Manager console on AWS, I see a session for each attempt I've done, they are all 'Terminated' and have a duration of around 15 seconds;
2. The SSM Agent logs on the target machine show the following error message for each attempt;

   ```
    Encountered error while initiating handshake. Handshake timed out. Please ensure that you have the latest version of the session manager plugin.
   ```
3. I've asked colleagues to see if they face any issues, and they do not;
4. I've performed the same command while connected to other WiFi networks, and it works as expected;
5. I've removed the last two parts, and it worked successfully (which does not solve the issue, since I am using this to then SSH into the target machine);

   ```
    aws ssm start-session --target i-ABC --region us-west-2
   ```

Items 1 and 2 provide little help, I've confirmed that I have the latest plugin version installed.

Items 3, 4 and 5 have helped me narrow down the issue, and I now think it must be related with my WiFi network and its setup.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I can solve this issue or get closer to its root cause? I truly appreciate any feedback.